# Downsize a matrix in which some entries are unknown

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I have a 2D grid (G= 250x250) and just about 100 points of this is known and the rest is unknown (NaN). I want to resize this matrix. My problem is that `imresize` cannot do it for me in MATLAB, because it deletes the known values for me and just gives a NaN matrix.

Anyone know about a method that can do it for me? A suggestion is to use an interpolation method (e.g. by using inverse distance weighting), but I am not sure whether it works or not or even is there any better method?

```
    G = NaN(250,250);
    a = ceil(rand(1,50)*250*250);
    b = ceil(rand(1,50)*250*250);
    G (a) = 1; G (b) = 0;
```

Comment: `imresize` returns `NaN`s because your original matrix has `NaN`s. I think you should replace the `NaN`s with zeroes, call imresize, and then optionally revert the zeroes back to `NaN`s. Also, what do you mean by "resize the matrix" -- do you want to interpolate or just add elements without changing the existing values in the matrix?

Comment: @ Eitan: I just want resize the matrix and assign those 100 data to the most suitable nodes on the coarse grid. I think if I use interpolation, the everything will be changed! So, I am looking for resizing the matrix without changing the values. Also, I cannot replace the NaN values with 0 or 1, because it will be mixed with my current known data and I loss the accuracy

Comment: imresize does not resize a matrix, but scales an image. This involves interpolation, so having NaNs will not work verly well..

Comment: @ Angainor: that is why I said that one solution may be using interpolation, but I do not how!

Comment: @Sam I'm not following you. Suppose you have `A = [1 2; 3 NaN];`. You just want to "pad" the matrix with zeros, to obtain, say, a 10x10 matrix (containing the original four elements and the rest zeros), or interpolate it to obtain a new 10x10 matrix?

Comment: @EitanT He wants to coarsen the matrix, i.e., lower its dimensions, while keeping the same non-NaN entries in 'suitable' positions. Which is not possible in general. I guess what he wants is some kind of binning.

Comment: What do you want to do if the known entries fall onto the same entry in the coarsened matrix?

Comment: @ Eitan: Actually I want to resize, but as I asked, my friends say that this problem is not image (or matrix) resizing, it will be interpolation! But, my aim is to honor those 100 data (or at least the maximum ones) Therefore, I think my problem will be interpolation rather than resizing, yes?

Comment: @ Angainor: I want to use those data on coarse grid, but how I can find the suitable location for those data on the coarse grid?

Comment: @Sam I suppose you'll have to interpolate, but you'll have to detect where most of the data lies first. You should to give a simple example of a matrix and what result you _expect_ to obtain...

Comment: @ Eitan: Yes I think so. Actually I have no idea about the results! I just want to assign the most suitable values for the resized matrix

Comment: @ Eitan and Angainor: let ask in this way, if I have some know points on a grid (G) and the how I should use them by interpolation and make a coarser grid? The problem is re-locating the fine data and use them on the coarse grid for interpolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
% find the non-NaN entries in G
idx = ~isnan(G);

% find their corresponding row/column indices
[i,j] = find(idx);

% resize your matrix as desired, i.e. scale the row/column indices
i = ceil(i*100/250);
j = ceil(j*100/250);

% write the old non-NaN entries to Gnew using accumarray
% you have to set the correct size of Gnew explicitly
% maximum value is chosen if many entries share the same scaled i/j indices
% NaNs are used as the fill
Gnew = accumarray([i, j], G(idx), [100 100], @max, NaN);
```

You can also choose a different accumulation function for accumarray if max is not suitable for you. And you can change the fill value from NaN to something else if it is not what you need.

Comment: thanks a lotttt. It work :), but how it works? can you please give me brief explanation? or webpage to read.

Comment: @Sam I annotated the code. I simply rescale the indices of rows and columns of non-nan entries and create the new matrix by assigning values to the new row/column indices. Very basic things, no interpolation. Read help of accumarray to understand what exactly it does.

Comment: @ Angainor: I think something is wrong :(. I mean, imagine that you are looking to a picture from a close distance (fine grid), in this case you see the details, but when you get far, the resolution will be changed and therefore the values will be changed accordingly. I mean, in the coarser grid, those values (un-NaN pixels) are not same as the finer values. In this case, one may need to interpolate the coarser central pixel, yes?

Comment: @Sam it really depends on what you want to do :) My code only does what is described above. If you can use it depends solely on you. I don't know about looking from a distance, I know how to program what you asked for in matlab. Decide how you want to treat the coarsened values, and set appropriate function instead of max in accumarray. Or do interpolation if what you want to do is interpolation. Play with it a bit, see what works.